# What's better performance-wise, Django TemplateView or explicit url/view statements?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-class-based-views

For the less interesting pages on my Django site I've set up simple urlpatterns like:

```
url(r'^somepage/', views.somepage),
url(r'^anotherpage/', views.anotherpage),
```

and corresponding function views of:

```
def somepage(request):
    return render(request, 'page1.html')

def anotherpage(request):
    return render(request, 'page2.html')
```

I'm wondering if importing a generic class-based view into urls.py is preferable, or if there's some hidden cost to climbing through inheritance, etc. that I'm missing:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^somepage/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='page1.html')),
    url(r'^anotherpage/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='page2.html')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Why don't you just benchmark? What you will find is that one will be about 2 milliseconds faster than the other.

Comment: The first version will be faster since it runs less code, but that doesn't really matter. Rendering a template (with any code that calls `render`) will be so much more expensive that the calling code is just a tiny fraction of the overall costs. BTW a core principle of Django's development is: server's are cheap, developers are expensive. So, it tries to run more code in order to make deveopment easier.